# How to display checkmark along with Spinner options using styles?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm trying to display a boolean checkmark along with each option in my spinner. I've tried to set the checkmark parameter in the styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/backgroundColor</item>
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/cardBackgroundColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_dark_spinner</item>
        <item name="android:checkMark">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle</item>
    </style> </resources>
```

and this in my Spinner:

```
<Spinner
            android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme"
            style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/unitsSpinner"
            android:entries="@array/units_array"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/text_color_hint"
            />
```

But my spinner options are looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lprS.jpg).
Is there any way to fix that? I would like to avoid creating a custom view just for fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing style of the spinner try to change the layout for the spinner. If you are using the default android layout then try to use **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice** layout for providing choice and if you are using custom layout you can use either checkbox or radiobutton based on usage.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Following these steps:

-Set the styles just like said in the question,

-Set the Spinner theme with the custom style:

```
   <Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/productCountSpinner"
    />
```

-In the java code, create an adapter with the layout resource simple_spinner_dropdown_item, and set it to the spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.units_array));
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mProductCountSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

This is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1UDb.png).